# Select only option with class name

Tags: jquery

By default, all options are selected. Then from `click` event which returns the class name (zzz), I want to show only the rest of the option with class='zzz'

```js
$(document).on('click', ".test" , function() {
      var selectedParent = $(this).val();
      alert(selectedParent); //returns zzz
      $('#users> option').each(function(){
         if ($(this).hasClass( "selectedParent" )){
             $(this).show();
         } else {
             $(this).hide();
      });
 });
```

```html
<select multiple="true" id="users" name="users[]">
<option selected="selected" value="1" class="zzz">User 1</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2" class="zzz">User 2</option>
<option selected="selected" value="3" class="aaa">User 3</option>
<option selected="selected" value="4" class="aaa">User 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Where is `class="test"` in your HTML?

Comment: Take the quotes off `selectedParent` to use the variable's value. Otherwise you're looking for the literal class `selectedParent`.

Comment: As @Barmar said there is no class named as test in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you quoted `selectedParent`, so it's not using the variable value.

Also, instead of using `.each()`, you can substitute the class into selectors.

```js
$(document).on('click', ".test", function() {
  var selectedParent = $(this).val();
  $(`#users > option.${selectedParent}`).show();
  $(`#users > option:not(.${selectedParent})`).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="true" id="users" name="users[]">
  <option selected="selected" value="1" class="zzz">User 1</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="2" class="zzz">User 2</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="3" class="aaa">User 3</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="4" class="aaa">User 4</option>
</select>
<br>
<button class="test" value="zzz">ZZZ</button>
<button class="test" value="aaa">AAA</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like an option:

```js
    $(document).on('click', "#users > option" , function() {
          var selectedParent = $(this).attr('class');
          $('#users>option').each(function(){
             if (!$(this).hasClass(selectedParent)){
                 $(this).hide();
             }
          });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="true" id="users" name="users[]">
  <option selected="selected" value="1" class="zzz">User 1</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="2" class="zzz">User 2</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="3" class="aaa">User 3</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="4" class="aaa">User 4</option>
</select>
```

Hope it helps.